# discrepancy in cookie expiration date

Tags: php, cookies

I'm creating a cookie which should never expire, so I set the expiration date to 2038-01-01:

`setcookie($keyword, $value, mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2038));`

I expected the expiration date/time to be set to

> 01 January 2038 00:00:00

but when I check it in Firefox's cookies I see

> 01 January 2038 08:00:12

Where does this discrepancy come from?

Comment: What timezone is your server set to?

Comment: @MarkBaker: that could be it, thanks. My server's time is EST, and I'm in Europe. Nevertheless, if I specify "00:00:00" shouldn't it set the time to "00:00:00", regardless of the time zone I'm in?

Answer (score 3):

`mktime` operates in the server's time zone. When you check Firefox's cookies, it shows them in your local time zone. If they're different, you'll see a discrepancy like this.

The `:12` in the seconds field is probably due to the server using the `Max-Age` cookie parameter rather than a precise `Expires`. `Max-Age` is calculated by the browser from the time it received the cookie, so there were apparently 12 seconds between the `setcookie()` call and when the browser received the response.